# Color a cell in MS Excel sheet, if do not fall in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, colors

We need to enter lots of data in a excel sheet. Later we want to color code that data.

I will be the one preparing this excel sheet and sharing with team. What I want is the moment I put a number and if it is not falling in range, cell will turn red else green i.e. I don't want to go through cells again and color code them.

I tried:

I found if formula `=if(200<C3<500,[value_if_true],[value_if_false])`

Here I have two problems,

1. `C3` should be direct input means I don't want to apply this formula on someother column.
2. I don't know the formula to color a cell if condition is not true/false.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-FED60DFA-1D3F-4E13-9ECB-F1951FF89D7F):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Formulas: `=NOT(AND(200<C3,C3<500))` and `=AND(200<C3,C3<500)` - assuming you wanted to colour a number OVER 200 and LESS THAN 500. Bear in mind, 200 and 500 are NOT inclusive with this formula.